# Is it idiomatic to use the present perfect simple to give an explanation for a present result?

Tags: present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

> I am tired  because I have been climbing the Eiffel Tower.

This focuses on the effort of climbing and the present perfect is used in an explanatory resultative fashion.
I am tired because climbing the tower is a strenuous activity.
I may or may not have reached the top, but that doesn't matter, the focus is on the activity.

Would it be possible to say:

> I am tired because I have just climbed the Eiffel Tower

when you have reached the top? Here the focus is on the achievement of having reached the top.Is this idiomatic?

Comment: "Present perfect simple" doesn't make sense.  The "simple" tenses are those that are not formed with auxiliary verbs.  And the present perfect is formed with an auxiliary verb.  So either "present perfect" or "simple present" but not "present perfect simple"

Answer (score 1):

Your final sentence is indeed correct and is also the only one that conveys that you have reached the pinnacle.

> I’ve been climbing

means you are or recently were in the process of increasing your altitude, whereas

> I’ve climbed

Means you’ve reached the top.